# How can I begin my table row text from the same line?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a very simple HTML table. It has a row, and each row has 4 columns. Each cell has some text of varying length. Thus they do not start on the same line as illustrated in the image I have attached.

How can I make the text start on the same line although the text in each cell is of variable length.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this css field on the td tag. That should make all the columns aligned to top.

```
vertical-align:top;
```